# Cannot integrate Firebase in Flutter - MissingPluginException

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication, server

I/flutter ( 1925): MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method createUserWithEmailAndPassword on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth)

I followed every steps in the video of The Net Ninja about Firebase Authentication but I keep getting the same error. Please help!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4d-gIPGzmK4&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9itfjle0ji1xOZ2cjRGY_WB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stop the execution then type the command `flutter clean` and finally `flutter run`